# HTML to pdf convertor in Java

Tags: html, image, pdf, base64

Requirement: Convert HTML file to pdf in java(In HTML , Image are encoded in base64 format)

Problem statement: I am getting output from another tool in HTML format in which images and data is present but images are in base64 format. I have to convert this HTML file to pdf with including all the data and images in proper manner.
                       however, i am easily able to convert html page to pdf but the images which are inside in html page (encoded in base64) are not coming in pdf
                      I have tried all the solution itext, flying saucer etc.. But not able to get result.

sample HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>`enter code here`
<html>
<h1> HTML FILE WITH BASE 64 IMAGE</h1>
<body>
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM/////
wAAACwAAAAADwAPAAACIISPeQHsrZ5ModrLlN48CXF8m2iQ3YmmKqVlRtW4ML
wWACH+H09wdGltaXplZCBieSBVbGVhZCBTbWFydFNhdmVyIQAAOw=="
alt="Base64 encoded image" width="150" height="150"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/). It is a command line tool that you can call from your Java application. The most recent builds will allow you to generate PDFs with base64 image formats. I actually just did this today. I believe you may need the x64 version though. Best of luck sir.

Comment: Hi Matt,
Thanks for the reply
Can you please share a sample code so that i can get the idea..

Thanks,
Solver

Comment: Hey Matt,

It worked but can you tell me how to install this  wkhtmltopdf on server ..
or it is possible to put wkhtmltopdf.exe file in my java program resource folder and excute??

Comment: I am so glad you were able to figure out the JSON parsing. Great job! As for wkhtmltopdf I will do my best to point you in the right direction. Go to the [official wkhtmltopdf downloads page](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) and download the appropriate pre-compiled binary. The only thing you should have to do after that is send the correct command line arguments to the executable. See the documentation [here](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt). Best of luck friend!

Comment: Hey Matt,
Thanks for the help ,I have completed my code as requiredand i have also added more functionality into it...

It will take multiple html file's from same folder and convert into pdf  and put all the files into dest. folder..:-)

Comment: Hey Champ, Please advice for converting images to pdf and my image length is very big.Please advice any tool like wkhtmltopdf so that i can use in java coding.

Comment: @Mr.Solver - I had the same issues. I was able to compress my PDF's using a really odd command line tool workaround similar to wkhtmltopdf. It uses ghostscript. I do NOT know why this works, but it works in about 4/5 cases for me. 

[Ask Ubuntu Link with Code Snippets](http://askubuntu.com/questions/113544/how-can-i-reduce-the-file-size-of-a-scanned-pdf-file)

Edit: Forgot link.